# can a computer create his binary file alone?

Tags: binary, hardware, binaryfiles, binary-data

we know that everything is binary and just 0 and 1 in computer hardware but if a file is sent from computer A to computer B the computer A send the whole data to B as binary , what if the computer A send the the computer B some sign and algorithm that make the computer B know what are the binaries , can the computer B create the binaries then by himself instead of sending the whole file or data from A to B ?

here i mean any kind of file photo, video, HTML and audio

sorry if my question seems not technical but I just want to figure it out

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It's called compression! [gzip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) is an example commonly used on the web.

Comment: gzip instead of sending a file it just tell the other computer how to create it and the other computer create it ?

Comment: gzip just send the same file but compressed in smaller size but i mean i send some numbers to another computer and the other computer take these numbers and by some algorithm he know what is the binary and he can make it by himself faster , without sending the file from A to B , so can a computer in first place create binaries by himself ?

Comment: "so can a computer in first place create binaries by himself ?" Not unless you know of better AI than I do. The thing with compressed files, is that it is said to be compressed because the data may be represented in such a way as to be smaller than the original. Hufman compression for instance, uses a table that contains the number of times each byte 0x00 - 0xFF appears in the file. It then sorts the table from most to least used and then represents often used characters with few bits and little used characters with many bits - usually resulting in a net saving. :)

Comment: ok thanks i guess i was thinking in the wrong direction